# Farseer ContactListener is not working

Tags: c#, xna, game-physics, farseer

I'm using Farseer in my XNA project, but I have some trouble with the ContactListener. I created a class for my ContactListener but I always get these two error messages and I don't know how to fix the problems.

The type or namespace name 'ContactListener' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'ContactImpulse' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What is wrong with my ContactListener class?

```
class MyContactListener: ContactListener
{
    void BeginContact(Contact contact)

    { /* handle begin event */ }


    void EndContact(Contact contact)

    { /* handle end event */ }


     void PreSolve(Contact contact, ref Manifold oldManifold)
    {
      Fixture fixtureA = contact.FixtureA;
      Fixture fixtureB = contact.FixtureB;

      if (fixtureB.CollisionCategories == Category.Cat10)
      {
        contact.Enabled = false;
      }
    }

    void PostSolve(Contact contact, ref ContactImpulse impulse)

   { /* handle post-solve event */ }

}
```

Comment: Did you add a reference to the farseer assemby to the project that contains this class. Did you add the containing namepace for 'ContactListener' as a using in the class file?

Comment: I added a reference to the Farseer project but I can not find a ContactListener class. Where can I find this class?

Comment: Which namespace should I add? I added already several namespaces.

Comment: I looked all over the Farseer source and I couldnt find `ContactListener` anywhere in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

- Open VS
- Go to the `Solution Explorer` window
- Search for a folder called `References` and right click it
- Select `Add Reference...`
- look for the Farseer assembly and add it

And try adding these in code:

```
using FarseerPhysics.Collision.Shapes;
using FarseerPhysics.Common;
using FarseerPhysics.Dynamics;
using FarseerPhysics.Dynamics.Contacts;
using FarseerPhysics.Factories;
using FarseerPhysics.TestBed.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I already added the reference before I asked my question here on stackoverflow.

Comment: I get this error message if I add the following using: using FarseerPhysics.TestBed.Framework;   The type or namespace name 'TestBed' does not exist in the namespace 'FarseerPhysics' (are you missing an assembly reference?)